# Django filter results from one table based on value from another table

Tags: django, filter

First model: user_accounts
user_id, description,bank_id

Second model: bank
id, name, bank_type

for example:

**user_accounts**

user_id     ,description   ,bank_id

555, test, 111

555           ,test1,        222

**bank**

id      ,name      ,bank_type

111     ,zzzz       ,local

222     ,mmmm       ,international

How to filter results from user_accounts based on value in bank_type?
For example: filter user_accounts on bank_type ='international'
That should return 555(user_id), test1(description), 222(bank_id)

Answer (score 3):

`UserAccount.objects.filter(bank__bank_type='international')`

That should do the trick; but without seeing your actual models file, I am taking a guess at your model names.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships should give you some indication of how this works.